# iCloud not fatching previous version data if i upgrade testing version on appstore version

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

My app using coredata with iCloud.

My application version is live on iTunes store version number 1.0.


I added new model version in coredata, 2 fields added in my coredata entity. version 2.0


iCloud with coredata working fine if i install the binary from xCode.

Working scenario is

 Install v1.0 form xcode archive.

 Enter some data in application

 Upgrade to v2.0 from xcode archive.

All things working with icloud.


Borken scenario is

 Download version 1.0 from app store. 

 Enter some data.

 Upgrade v2.0 from xcode archive, Data missing from iCloud.

I don't know what i am missing.. But something wrong with itunes version to archive version upgrade.

Comment: iCloud data manage stack is different for live version and testing version?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform lightweight automatic migration with CoreData, you simply need to add it as an option in your persistentStoreCoordinator delegate method:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"your_coredata_database.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

There are limits to coredata migration, but small tweaks should migrate without hassle.